# Optimizing a Haskell program

Tags: optimization, haskell

I started looking at Haskell yesterday with the goal of actually learning it. I've written some trivial programs with it in programming language courses, but none of them really cared about efficiency. I'm trying to understand how to improve the running time of the following program.

My program solves the following toy problem (I know it's simple to compute the answer by hand if you know what a factorial is, but I'm doing it the brute force way with a successor function):

http://projecteuler.net/problem=24

My algorithm for the successor function for lexicographic ordering given a list of finite length is the following:

1. If the list is already in decreasing order, then we have the maximal element in the lexicographic ordering, so there's no successor.
2. Given a list h : t, either t is maximal in the lexicographic ordering or it's not. In the latter case compute the successor of t. In the former case proceed as follows.
3. Pick the smallest element d in t larger than h.
4. Replace d with h in t giving a new list t'. The next element in the ordering is d : (sort t')

My program that implements this is the following (lots of these function are probably in the standard library):

```
max_list :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
max_list []     = error "Empty list has no maximum!"
max_list (h:[]) = h
max_list (h:t)  = max h (max_list t)

min_list :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
min_list []     = error "Empty list has no minimum!"
min_list (h:[]) = h
min_list (h:t)  = min h (min_list t)

-- replaces first occurrence of x in list with y
replace :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replace _ _ []  = []
replace x y (h:t)
    | h == x    = y : t
    | otherwise = h : (replace x y t)

-- sort in increasing order
sort_list :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
sort_list []    = []
sort_list (h:t) = (sort_list (filter (\x -> x <= h) t))
               ++ [h]
               ++ (sort_list (filter (\x -> x > h) t))

-- checks if list is in descending order
descending :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Bool
descending []     = True
descending (h:[]) = True
descending (h:t)
    | h > (max_list t) = descending t
    | otherwise        = False

succ_list :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
succ_list []      = []
succ_list (h:[])  = [h]
succ_list (h:t)
    | descending (h:t)   = (h:t)
    | not (descending t) = h : succ_list t
    | otherwise = next_h : sort_list (replace next_h h t)
    where next_h = min_list (filter (\x -> x > h) t)

-- apply function n times
apply_times :: (Integral n) => n -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
apply_times n _ a
    | n <= 0      = a
apply_times n f a = apply_times (n-1) f (f a)

main = putStrLn (show (apply_times 999999 succ_list [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]))
```

Now the actual question. After noticing that my program took a while to run, I wrote an equivalent C program for comparison. My guess is that the lazy evaluation of Haskell causes the apply_times function to build a huge list in memory before it actually starts evaluating the result. I had to increase the runtime stack size for it to run. Since efficient Haskell programming seems to be about tricks, are there any nice tricks that could be used to minimize memory consumption? What about ways to minimize copying and garbage collection, since lists keep getting created over and over while a C implementation would do everything in place.

Since Haskell is supposedly efficient, I guess there has to be a way? One cool thing that I have to say about Haskell though is that the program worked correctly the first time it compiled, so that part of the language does seem to fill it's promise.

Comment: are you compiling with `-O2`?  As to the standard library, are you aware of Hoogle?

Comment: Profile your code and see the bottlenecks

Comment: Efficient Haskell programming isn't about tricks.  It's about having a good understanding of Haskell's (and GHC's) evaluation model.  The performance characteristics of different approaches are then usually quite clear.

Comment: @PhilipJF: Nope, I did not know about Hoogle. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> lots of these function are probably in the standard library

Indeed. If you `import Data.List`, that makes `sort` available, `maximum` and `minimum` are available from the `Prelude`. The `sort` from `Data.List` is all in all more efficient than the quasi-quicksort, in particular since you have a lot of sorted chunks in the lists here.

```
descending :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Bool
descending []     = True
descending (h:[]) = True
descending (h:t)
    | h > (max_list t) = descending t
    | otherwise        = False
```

is inefficient - `O(n²)` - since it traverses the entire left tail in each step, although if the list is descending, the maximum of the tail must be its head.  **But** that has a nice consequence here. It prevents the build-up of thunks, since the first guard of the third equation of `succ_list` forces the list to be completely evaluated. However, that could be done more efficiently with an explicit forcing of the list *once*.

```
descending (h:t@(ht:_)) = h > ht && descending t
```

would make it linear. That

> After noticing that my program took a while to run, I wrote an equivalent C program for comparison.

That would be unusual. Few would even go so far to use a linked list in C, implementing lazy evaluation on top of that would be quite an undertaking.

Writing an *equivalent* programme in C would be extremely unidiomatic. In C, the natural way to implement the algorithm would use an array and in-place mutation. That is automatically much more efficient here.

> My guess is that the lazy evaluation of Haskell causes the apply_times function to build a huge list in memory before it actually starts evaluating the result.

Not quite, what it builds is a huge thunk,

```
apply_times 999999 succ_list [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
~> apply_times 999998 succ_list (succ_list [0 .. 9])
~> apply_times 999997 succ_list (succ_list (succ_list [0 .. 9]))
~> apply_times 999996 succ_list (succ_list (succ_list (succ_list [0 .. 9])))
...
succ_list (succ_list (succ_list ... (succ_list [0 .. 9])...))
```

and, after that thunk has been built, it must be evaluated. To evaluate the outermost call, the next must be evaluated far enough to find out which pattern matches in the outermost call. So the outermost call is pushed on a stack, and the next call is started to be evaluated. For that, it must be determined which pattern matches, so part of the result of the third call is needed. Thus the second call is pushed on the stack ... . At the end, you have 999998 calls on the stack and start to evaluate the innermost call. Then you play a bit of ping-pong between each call and the next outer call (at least, the dependencies might spread a bit further) while bubbling up and popping calls from the stack.

> are there any nice tricks that could be used to minimize memory consumption

Yes, force the intermediate lists to be evaluated before they become the argument of `apply_times`. You need complete evaluation here, so the vanilla `seq` is not good enough

```
import Control.DeepSeq

apply_times' :: (NFData a, Integral n) => n -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
apply_times' 0 _ x = x
apply_times' k f x = apply_times' (k-1) f $!! f x
```

that prevents the build-up of thunks, and thus you don't need more memory than for a few short lists constructed in `succ_list`, and the counter.

> What about ways to minimize copying and garbage collection, since lists keep getting created over and over while a C implementation would do everything in place.

Right, that would still allocate (and garbage collect) a lot. Now, GHC is **very** good in allocating and garbage collecting short-lived data (on my box, it can easily allocate at a rate of 2GB per MUT second without being slow), but still, *not allocating* all those lists would be faster.

So, if you want to push it, use in-place mutation. Work on an

```
STUArray s Int Int
```

or an unboxed mutable Vector (I prefer the interface provided by the `array` package, but most prefer the `vector` interface; in terms of performance, the `vector` package has a lot of optimisations built-in for you, if you use the `array` package, you have to write the fast code yourself, but well-written code performs equal for all practical purposes).

---

I've done a bit of testing now. I have not tested the original lazy `apply_times`, only the one `deepseq`ing each application of `f`, and have fixed the type of all involved entities as `Int`.

With that set-up, replacing `sort_list` with `Data:list.sort` reduced the running time from 1.82 seconds to 1.65 (but increased the number of allocated bytes). Not too much of a difference, but the lists are not long enough to make the bad cases for the quasi-quicksort really bite.

The big difference then comes from changing `descending` as proposed, that brought the time down to 0.48 seconds, Alloc rate    2,170,566,037 bytes per MUT second, 0.01 seconds GC time (and then using `sort_list` instead of `sort` brings the time up to 0.58 seconds).

Replacing the sorting of the ending segment of the list with a simpler `reverse` - the algorithm guarantees that it is sorted in descending order when it is sorted - brings down the time to 0.43 seconds.

A fairly direct translation of the algorithm to use unboxed mutable arrays,

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main (main) where

import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Base
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad (when, replicateM_)

sortPart :: STUArray s Int Int -> Int -> Int -> ST s ()
sortPart a lo hi
   | lo < hi   = do
       let lscan !p h i
               | i < h = do
                   v <- unsafeRead a i
                   if p < v then return i else lscan p h (i+1)
               | otherwise = return i
           rscan !p l i
               | l < i = do
                   v <- unsafeRead a i
                   if v < p then return i else rscan p l (i-1)
               | otherwise = return i
           swap i j = do
               v <- unsafeRead a i
               unsafeRead a j >>= unsafeWrite a i
               unsafeWrite a j v
           sloop !p l h
               | l < h = do
                   l1 <- lscan p h l
                   h1 <- rscan p l1 h
                   if (l1 < h1) then (swap l1 h1 >> sloop p l1 h1) else return l1
               | otherwise = return l
       piv <- unsafeRead a hi
       i <- sloop piv lo hi
       swap i hi
       sortPart a lo (i-1)
       sortPart a (i+1) hi
   | otherwise = return ()

descending :: STUArray s Int Int -> Int -> Int -> ST s Bool
descending arr lo hi
    | lo < hi   = do
        let check i !v
                | hi < i    = return True
                | otherwise = do
                    w <- unsafeRead arr i
                    if w < v
                      then check (i+1) w
                      else return False
        x <- unsafeRead arr lo
        check (lo+1) x
    | otherwise = return True

findAndReplace :: STUArray s Int Int -> Int -> Int -> ST s ()
findAndReplace arr lo hi
    | lo < hi   = do
        x <- unsafeRead arr lo
        let go !mi !mv i
                | hi < i    = when (lo < mi) $ unsafeWrite arr mi x >> unsafeWrite arr lo mv
                | otherwise = do
                    w <- unsafeRead arr i
                    if x < w && w < mv
                      then go i w (i+1)
                      else go mi mv (i+1)
            look i
                | hi < i    = return ()
                | otherwise = do
                    w <- unsafeRead arr i
                    if x < w
                      then go i w (i+1)
                      else look (i+1)
        look (lo+1)
    | otherwise = return ()

succArr :: STUArray s Int Int -> Int -> Int -> ST s ()
succArr arr lo hi
    | lo < hi   = do
        end <- descending arr lo hi
        if end
          then return ()
          else do
              needSwap <- descending arr (lo+1) hi
              if needSwap
                then do
                    findAndReplace arr lo hi
                    sortPart arr (lo+1) hi
                else succArr arr (lo+1) hi
    | otherwise = return ()

solution :: [Int]
solution = runST $ do
    arr <- newListArray (0,9) [0 .. 9]
    replicateM_ 999999 $ succArr arr 0 9
    getElems arr

main :: IO ()
main = print solution
```

completes in 0.15 seconds. Replacing the sorting with a simpler reversing of the part brings it down to 0.11.

Splitting the algorithm into small top-level functions that each do one task makes it more readable, but that comes at a price. More parameters need to be passed between the functions, consequently not all can be passed in registers, and some of the passed parameters - the array bounds and element count - are not used at all, so that's dead weight being passed. Making all other functions local functions in `solution` reduces the overall allocation and running time somewhat (0.13 seconds with sorting, 0.09 with reversing), since now only the necessary parameters need to be passed.

Deviating further from the given algorithm and making it work back to front,

```
module Main (main) where

import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Base
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad (when)
import Data.Bits

lexPerm :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
lexPerm idx num = elems (runSTUArray $ do
    arr <- unsafeNewArray_ (0,num)
    let fill i
            | num < i   = return ()
            | otherwise = unsafeWrite arr i i >> fill (i+1)
        swap i j = do
            x <- unsafeRead arr i
            y <- unsafeRead arr j
            unsafeWrite arr j x
            unsafeWrite arr i y
        flop i j
            | i < j     = do
                swap i j
                flop (i+1) (j-1)
            | otherwise = return ()
        binsearch v a b = go a b
          where
            go i j
              | i < j     = do
                let m = (i+j+1) `unsafeShiftR` 1
                w <- unsafeRead arr m
                if w < v
                  then go i (m-1)
                  else go m j
              | otherwise = swap a i
        upstep k j
            | k < 1     = return ()
            | j == num-1 = unsafeRead arr num >>= flip (back k) (num-1)
            | otherwise  = nextP k (num-1)
        back k v i
            | i < 0     = return ()
            | otherwise = do
                w <- unsafeRead arr i
                if w < v
                  then nextP k i
                  else back k w (i-1)
        nextP k up
            | k < 1 || up < 0   = return ()
            | otherwise = do
                v <- unsafeRead arr up
                binsearch v up num
                flop (up+1) num
                upstep (k-1) up
    fill 0
    nextP (idx-1) (num-1)
    return arr)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ lexPerm 1000000 9
```

we can complete the task in 0.02 seconds.

The clever algorithm alluded to in the question, however, solves the task with far less code in much less time.

Comment: Thanks! So thunk is the correct word for (f (f ... (f x)...)? I was not aware how you could force everything to be evaluated. I'll look into how to use vectors and arrays, since these haven't been mentioned in the Haskell sources that I've looked at. BTW, for some reason on my box the built-in "sort" is actually slower than my "sort_list"...

Comment: A thunk is, shall we say, a piece of code that computes a value when it is executed. Pretty much every value starts out as a thunk (well, not every value, `'a'` or `True` are already evaluated). So when you have `map f (x:xs)`, that is a thunk, and when the result is demanded, it is first evaluated one step to `(f x) : (map f xs)`. Then we have an evaluated value - the first cons-cell - and that contains pointers to two further thunks, `f x` and `map f xs`. When either of these two thunks is demanded, it is evaluated further, as far as it is demanded. (to be continued)

Comment: So that's a good thing, you have part of the result early, and what you don't need won't be evaluated at all. But on the other hand, big nested thunks can be built, and then, to evaluate even a small part of it, a lot of work needs to be done. So it's a double-edged sword. Therefore it is necessary to have means to force evaluation (partially or completely), before it is necessitated by the data-dependencies alone. Thus we have the magic `seq` and `deepseq`.

Comment: Regarding the speed of the sorting functions, I'm surprised, have you compiled the code with `-O2`? `Data.List.sort` wins a lot by that. It comfortably beat a quasi-quicksort on all my boxes on average (it can be a bit slower on nicely randomised lists, but that is - in my experience - more than compensated by the lists with sorted and/or reverse sorted streaks). In the situation at hand, sorting the end of the list means reversing it, and that is the optimal case for `Data.List.sort`, so if `sort_list` is really faster, that is doubly surprising. What is your GHC version and OS?

Comment: Yeah, I realized that the evaluation must work in this fashion, since otherwise you could not map on infinite lists. It's good to know you can override it. I have actually compiled with -O2, so I was pretty surprised by this. Instead of sort, it's actually possible to use reverse here, which cuts 20% of the runtime, since the list is guaranteed to be still descending after the replacement. I'm running GHC 7.0.4 on Fedora 16 (64 bit)

Comment: Hmm, odd. 7.0.4 already has the new `sort` code, so on a reverse-sorted list it's basically one traversal reversing the descending sublist. I can't imagine Fedora would ship a compiler whose libraries would be built without optimisations, so I don't understand it at all.